# How to get records greater than selected year and month when the year is greater and month is less than specified one in Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I am using Yii2 basic. I have a table called groupsavingdetails. In that table I have records for a specific group with Id 29 and from year 2017 and Months August, September, October, November and December. Also there are records for the same group for year 2018 January and March.

The situation is I want to update record whose year is 2017 and month is September. Now I want to get all the records greater than September 2017 record. Total 5 records should I get but only 3 records are fetched by the following query.

```
SELECT * FROM groupsavingdetails WHERE groupsavingdetails.GroupId=29 and Year>=2017 and Month>9
```

Below is the image of table contaning records. So I should get records from Id 47,48,49,51,52. How should I get it.

[image]

Comment: Try `WHERE CONCAT(month,"-",year) >= "09 - 2017" AND GroupId = 29`

Comment: No still all records are displayed

Comment: Removed space `WHERE CONCAT(Month,"-",Year) >= "9-2017" AND GroupId = 29`

Comment: No, now the september months record is displayed

Comment: your `month` column is `INT` and `year` is `YEAR` in DB Structure?

Comment: Yes both of them are int

Comment: could you please provide an text sample of your data or even better a dbfiddle example?

Comment: Which data? Table structure or raw sql create statement

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM groupsavingdetails WHERE 
groupsavingdetails.GroupId=29 
and ( Year > 2017 or (Year>=2017 and Month > 9) )
```

In This query

if year is greater than 2017 it will display

and year is 2017 and month is greater than 9 also display

Comment: Thankyou. This also works for me. Is it correct. SELECT * FROM groupsavingdetails WHERE ((groupsavingdetails.GroupId=29 and Year>=2017 and Month>9) OR (GroupId=29 and Year>2017AND Month>0))

Comment: Both are same,but you are using twice ---> 'groupsavingdetails.GroupId=29'

Comment: So can I use the one refered by you or the second one. Which is efficient?

Comment: I think less condition in query is faster than other

Comment: Hi , Now the situation is when I want to change September months record, then its closing balance will get changed and thus this new closing balance will be set to opening balance for the October month and so on. How should I do this?

Comment: i think, you are change these 'year' and 'month' dynamically